# My mod_rewrite won't work, what's wrong?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the following rewrite rule, but nothing is hapenning at all when I try to use it. I have the file in the directory server.blahblahblah.com/todo and the following is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^tasks/view/([0-9]+)?/$ controller.php?task=view&id=$1
RewriteRule ^tasks/view/([0-9]+)\.xml$ controller.php?task=viewxml&id=$1
RewriteRule ^tasks/new?/$ controller.php?task=new
RewriteRule ^tasks/delete/([0-9]+)?/$ controller.php?task=delete&id=$1
RewriteRule ^tasks/completed/([0-9]+)?/$ controller.php?task=complete&id=$1
RewriteRule ^tasks?/$ controller.php?task=home
```

Does anyone know why this won't work at all?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

If nothing happens at all, it might be that you didn't enable .htaccess files for your site. To do that, change your site configuration (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<yoursite>`) to include `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride None` (the default). But mind the performance disadvantage - you could also put the rules directly in the site configuration.

In case that doesn't solve it, look at the Apache logs in `/var/log/apache2/*`.